# How to alert message once and not multiple times - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, alert

I have a function

```
        function postItems(){
            var url = baseURL + "order_items/"
            var oucu = $("#salesPerson").val()
            for (var i = 0; i < currentItems.length; ++i) {
                $.post(url, {
                    OUCU: oucu,
                    password: password,
                    order_id: currentOrderId,
                    widget_id: currentItems[i][0],
                    number: currentItems[i][1],
                    pence_price: currentItems[i][2]

                }, function(data) {
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                    if (obj.status == "success") {
                        alert("Order has been placed");
                    } else {
                        alert(obj.message);
                    }
                })

            }
        }
```

Right now it alerts me the order has been placed after every item has been posted. Is there a way i can get it to tell me this only once, after all the items have been posted to the API? I can't access `obj.status` if i move the alert outside the callback function.

Comment: Have you considered saving the message to a list or array outside of the loop and then processing that to produce any messages required?

Comment: You are going to run into some coordination problems if you use a sync loop to handle an async operation. Consider implementing an async loop and supply a callback which will be fired when the whole post operation is complete.

Comment: You do NOT want to make the $.post request inside a for loop. Just do not. What you want is to do one request an passing the entire array of `currentItems`  (I believe it is an array) then do the things you need to do on the server side. And then you will get one alert message for one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of processed orders and fire alert() once all orders are processed:

```
    var ordersProcessed = [];
    function postItems(){
        var url = baseURL + "order_items/"
        var oucu = $("#salesPerson").val()
        for (var i = 0; i < currentItems.length; ++i) {
            $.post(url, {
                OUCU: oucu,
                password: password,
                order_id: currentOrderId,
                widget_id: currentItems[i][0],
                number: currentItems[i][1],
                pence_price: currentItems[i][2]

            }, function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                ordersProcessed.push(obj);
                if(ordersProcessed.length == currentItems.length) {
                    var message = "";
                    for(var x = 0; x < ordersProcessed.length; x++) {
                        if(ordersProcessed[x].status == "success")
                            message += "Order has been placed";
                        else
                            message += ordersProcessed[x].message;
                        message += "\n";
                    }
                    alert(message);                  
                }
            })

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something a lot cleaner like this.

```
// function to post items to the server
function postItems (options, items, done) {
    items.forEach(function (item, index, items) {
        var lastItemIndex = items.length - 1
        $.post(options.url, {
            ouch: option.ouch,
            password: option.password,
            order_id: option.currentOrderId,
            widget_id: item[0],
            number: item[1],
            pence_price: item[2]
        }, function (data) {
            if (index < lastItemIndex) return;
            return done($.parseJSON(data));
        });
    })
}

// usage
postItems({url: "/serverUrl", ouch:'someString', password: 'itsASecret'}, ["item", "collection", "goes", "here"], function(data){
    alert(data.message);
});
```